# Combine multiple command in one line

Tags: linux, shell-script, find

```
#!/bin/sh
export origin=/home/user
export dest=/home/temp
find $origin -iname "*.png" -mtime -5 -exec cp "{}" $dest \;
find $origin -iname "*.png" -mtime -5 -exec zip $dest/png.zip "{}" \;
find $origin -iname "*.png" -mtime -5 -printf "%TY-%Tm-%Td %p\n"
```

I create a script which find the file from 5 days ago. Then copy it into temp folder, then zip it. After that, I display the content which found. Can I just combine the 3 command or at least top 2 in one line?

Comment: `find` allow multiple `-exec` options

Comment: @Archemar Can you show the code how it done

Comment: There is no need to `export` those shell variables.

Answer (score 1):

I would try

```
find $origin -iname "*.png" -mtime -5 -exec cp "{}" $dest \; -exec zip $dest/png.zip "{}" \; -printf "%TY-%Tm-%Td %p\n"
```

Comment: I don't know if it makes much of a difference here, but `-exec` also acts as a _test_, which means that if the utility exits with a non-zero exit status, the next `-exec` would not be performed.  This is different from the logic in the original code, which runs the three actions regardless of the outcome of the previous. You also need to quote the variable expansions (but not `{}`).

Comment: thanks, this one help me. But I wonder I can improve the output for 'printf' for this 1 line command. The output stack with the zip status and printed output. Unlike the separate command, the all zip status display first, then the all 'printf' display together.

Comment: @qwerty If you want the output in that particular order, then you have to run the commands in that order, as you already do, alternatively write the output to files from `find` and then display these in the correct order (which strikes me as a bit awkward).

Comment: @Kusalananda Yeah that's what I think.

Comment: Why would you copy the file to a directory and then also add the file to a zip file in the same directory?   If you're going to copy them to the directory, why use find to add them to the zip and not just add everything in the directory to the zip without find?